# How do I get my SSD to work as the primary drive for a new Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I have a 500GB Samsung SSD that used to be in my old MacBook Pro.  I've been using as an external hard-drive with my new MacBook for a while.

I'm building a new "Windows 10 Home" PC and I want to use the SSD as the primary drive in the PC.

I used the Mac "Disk Utility" to re-format the SSD to "FAT".

Then I plugged the drive into a Windows 7 laptop, right-clicked on the drive, and selected "format" to NTFS.

When I open the Windows "Disk Management" utlity, it looks like this (screenshot attached) ...

There appears to be three partitions ... "200 MB EFI System Partion", "465 GB Primary Partion" and "128 Unallocated".

What do I have to do to this harddrive so it is one big "500GB" partition that is a bootable drive, ready for a new Window 10 Home installation?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question ... the SSD was good as it.

My understanding is, the "EFI" partition is required for the drive to be bootable.

I installed Windows 10 on it without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title:

*How do I know if my SSD drive can be used as the primary drive for a new Windows 10 PC?*

If it is a regular SSD (and yours is) then it just will work.  There is nothing special to check here.

To answer the body question (which is quite different from the title):

*What do I have to do to this harddrive so it is one big "500GB" partition that is a bootable drive, ready for a new Window 10 Home installation?*

- Either create the expected system partitions. (ESP, msreserve, and a volume for the OS probably works).
- Alternatively. Leave it empty or even wipe it. Windows tends to be annoying if it does not get the partitions it wants and in the right sequence. And you want at least one boot partition (the ESP, with an EFI filesystem, which just happens to be FAT compatible) and a NTFS partition for the OS.

Note that 500GB is plenty. Even if you loose 1GB (2% of the whole disk) then that is worth it so save lots of potential future problems. And you will **see** just one single partition in your explorer window.

Comment: Thanks.  Edited the subject/question to make it more accurate to the body.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the SSD as it is currently formatted (with 200MB EFI partition, and the 465GB NTFS partition) is ready to have Windows 10 installed on it, correct?

Comment: Yes. seems about right.  Mine (win10 default) is 450MB, 100MB, 475*GB, 500MB. But why even pre-format it? The installer will take care off it. Either if you select wipe the disk and use the defaults, as well if you manually create a D: volume for data in the setup program.

Comment: *seems about right* if and only if the drive is GPT and you can install Windows in UEFI mode (Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode and MBR for Legacy/BIOS). A "new PC" is UEFI therefore you should use that mode for installing.

Comment: True. There used to be MBR on IBM PC compatible computers, but that has not been the default for many years. It is needed for XP, but win7 supported EFI and we're quite a few years after win7 now, and the question is tagged win10. So I prefer not to even mention it.